# remove old revision from svn server

Tags: svn, svndumpfilter

I don't have enough space to commit my changes in a svn server, there is a way to delete some old revisions of file so i can commit again, there is another way to gain space? 
I'm not an administrator of the svn server.

Comment: If you aren't the administrator, then I strongly suggest that you talk to the administrator.

Comment: If you're not the admin have you considered asking the admin to add more disks to the server, or to move the repository to one with more space?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you aren't admin, you can't do it. Real admin can do it and know how to to it in a best way!

**Doing your own thing!**

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to lose the complete history, then you have to [delete parts of subversion history](http://www.emilmont.net/doku.php?id=tools%3asvn#delete_parts_of_subversion_history), but if the used disk space is more important than the version history, you could make a **clean checkout** and **reimport** your projects into a new repository. The old repositories could then be stored in a compressed archive.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html) to accomplish this, but the real solution is to get a new server.  Disk space is not sufficiently expensive that selectively poking holes in your history seems like a reasonable thing to do.